# making a staircase of x's using loops in C, but I keep getting squares

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested

So I need to make a staircase but I clearly have something wrong with my logic. Any advice on how to approach this? I only end up getting squares.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a,b,z,y,p;
    char x;

    scanf("%i ", &a);
    printf("Number of stairs is: %i\n", a);
    printf("up: \n");

    for(b=0; b<a; b++) {
        for(z=1; a>=z; z++) {
            x='x';
            p=1;

            if ((p=z)) {
                printf("%c", x);
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }               
            p++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have double parentheses in `if ((p=z))`? My guess is you did that to silence a compiler warning when you originally wrote `if (p=z)`. Don't silence that warning. Get rid of the double parentheses, read that compiler warning, and heed it. Don't work around it.

Comment: i took the parentheses out and I'm not getting any error. I put that parentheses in a while ago when I was getting bothered by the compiler but that's not the case any more. any suggestions?

Comment: What do you think `p=z` does?

Comment: `x` is always assigned to `char x`, so I would just use `print( "x" );` and do away with `char x`

Comment: The others are right about p=z, but as another suggestion, perhaps the code would be easier to understand, and get right, if you name the variables something more meaningful than a, b, z, y  and p?

Comment: I'd use `putchar('x');` on that printing...

Comment: `p` is incremented at the end of your loop, but forced to 1 early in the loop next time around.  It seems like you did not mean for that to happen, or you would not have incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has many flaws and lack of clarity is one of them. Nevertheless, the reason you have a square is because `p=z` is always true (setting the value of `p` to `z` returns the value of `z` and this, in your code is always 1 or higher - a true value for C standards).

Here is a code that works, loosely based on your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    int numberSteps,currentStep,currentColumn;    
    scanf("%i", &numberSteps);
    printf("Number of stairs is: %i\n", numberSteps);
    printf("up: \n");    
    for(currentStep=0; currentStep<numberSteps; currentStep++) {
        for(currentColumn=0; currentStep>=currentColumn; currentColumn++) {            
            printf("x");            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Please notice that I changed the variable names so that they became meaningful and also got rid of the unnecessary variables and the unnecessary test `if ((p=z))` that was cluttering your code.

Comment: many thanks. I'm new to programming, that's why my lack of everything is so clear. will try your advise!